# How to get os.listdir to list files in order

Tags: python

I'm wanting to rename all of the files in a directory. When sorted by name in Windows Explorer, they appear in the correct order:

```
Cue 001 - 002.mp3
...
Cue 001 - 010.mp3
Cue 001 - 011.mp3
...
Cue 001 - 020.mp3
Cue 001 - 021.mp3
...
Cue 001 - 0111.mp3
Cue 001 - 0112.mp3
```

So far I've been able to use `os.chdir` to change the working directory to the directory having the target files, and confirm by using `print (os.getcwd())`.

```
import os
# Lets change working directory to the Python Rename Test folder
os.chdir(r'F:\My backup\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\My         Music\The Commitments\The Commitments - Mustang Sally_Recursive\Backup\Python Rename Test')
# confirm working directory by printing it out
print (os.getcwd())
# loop over the files in the working directory and printing them out
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print (file)
```

This is what I get:

```
Cue 001 - 002.mp3
...
Cue 001 - 010.mp3
Cue 001 - 0100.mp3
Cue 001 - 0101.mp3
...
```

How can I get `os.listdir` to print the files in the proper order?

Comment: Try `for file in sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))`

Comment: You should first define perhaps what `order` means in this context.... is is a purely sorted by the full name, or by the numeric part of the name.... Is it by extension first ?... etc

Comment: There is no canonical ordering here, what is "proper order"?

Comment: As an aside, If you want to rename the files, do you care that its done in alphabetical order?

Comment: @omu_negru Thank you. sorted by the numerical value preceding the extension

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. sorted by the numerical value preceding the extension

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you. sorted by the numerical value preceding the extension

Comment: @coolioasjulio I copied and pasted your suggestion and Debug resulted in invalid syntax hinting at the parentheses opening  after sorted. Looked okay as I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the files sorted by the number directly preceding the file extension.

```
import re

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
sorted_files = sorted(files,key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'\D','',x.strip())[3:]))
print(sorted_files)
```

Comment: thanks again.  
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined
How should I define "lines"?
I appreciate the help

Comment: Sorry that was a typo replace lines with files

Comment: Thanks.I replaced lines with files and got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I'm not sure how your file system is structured but you should make sure there aren't any other files in the folder. If there are, you can filter them out before sorting.

Comment: the folder, the path to which I hard coded into the script is a subfolder of the eventual target, with copies of it's files to experiment on, just so I could test the code. Nothing else in there but it's nice to know it can be filtered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code sorts by both numbers in case your files have a first number that is over `100` too.

```
In[2]: import re
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def sorted_by_nums(filenames):
  ...:     """Assuming filenames are in this format 'Cue 001 - 002.mp3'"""
  ...:     def by_nums(filename):
  ...:         *nums, _ = re.findall(r'\d+', filename)
  ...:         return [int(num) for num in nums]
  ...: 
  ...:     return sorted(filenames, key=by_nums)
  ...: 
In[3]: filenames = [
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 010.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 011.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 0112.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 0111.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 002.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 020.mp3',
  ...:     'Cue 001 - 021.mp3'
  ...: ]
# you could replace `filenames` with `os.listdir(...)` below
In[4]: for file in sorted_by_nums(filenames):
  ...:     print(file)
  ...: 
Cue 001 - 002.mp3
Cue 001 - 010.mp3
Cue 001 - 011.mp3
Cue 001 - 020.mp3
Cue 001 - 021.mp3
Cue 001 - 0111.mp3
Cue 001 - 0112.mp3
```